# Aligning equation with another equation after text

Tags: align

I was just wondering, if it was possible to align equations if there are text between them ?
I mean, if you have several equations right after each other you can use the `\begin{align}` command with `&` where you want them to align.

But lets say I have the following:

```
This equation is good:

[equation 1]

But this is also good:

[equation 2]

But these 2 are the best equations ever produced:

[equation 3]

[equation 4]
```

Is there any way to align all the 4 equations with each other then ?